# Which common api to be used to send data from server when server is in source mode

Tags: mirrorlink

I am writing mirrorlink-server data services(CDB/SBP) module.

However, all the common APIs of Data Services (8 manager and 5 listener) seem to be useful only when server is in sink mode.

When I will get a GET, SET or SUBSCRIBE command from client, which common API is to be used to notify the server application about the request so that application can fill the object and response can be sent back to the client?

Otherwise, what data will server send as response if it can't notify to the server application?

Answer (score 0):

The phone (server) can be data source for the head unit (client) but support is optional for both the phone and the head unit. There aren't many phones or head units that support it at this time.

The Common API does not (currently) define how to provide a data object as a source. This will be defined in a future revision as an additional service module.